# Hyperref under section don't link to items

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, itemize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can individual items in an itemize list be labelled and hyperref linked?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81949/can-individual-items-in-an-itemize-list-be-labelled-and-hyperref-linked)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\ref{itm:tre} 
\section{Referenser}
\begin{itemize}
\item \label{itm:tre} item number three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Why does it refer to the section and not the item? I want the reference marker to be [3] with a red three, and [3] with black three at the itemlist. Any suggestions?

Comment: `itemize` is non-numbered, so the items can't be referenced. You want `enumerate`. More precisely, please read the documentation on *bibliographies*.

Comment: I tried enumerate instead of itemize and still the same issue. Do you mean I should use another package? This seems kind of standard shouldn't it work the way I tried with something that counts as list or item?

Comment: @kuke Please update your MWE to `enumerate`. It's nearly inconceivable it doesn't work this way. Furthermore, instead of constructing a bibliography by hand like this, it's way better to use the dedicated LaTeX constructs. Please please read the manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\phantomsection` to add an anchor for hyperref. But the number printed by the \ref will still be the number of the section:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\ref{itm:tre}
\section{Referenser}
\newpage %to better see the target of the link
\begin{itemize}
\item \phantomsection\label{itm:tre} item number three
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ops misclick...