# How to refer to number of items in a list before the list appears in the .tex file?

Tags: lists, enumerate, counters

I would like LaTeX to "know" how many items there are in a certain list. I want this number to be stored in a variable. In such a way I hope that this variable is sampled during the first compilation and available for the next compilations. Then I can refer to the number of items in my text before the list appears in the same text. How can I accomplish that? My minimum example does not work. Thanks in advance :)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

%The following list contains \NumberOfItems\ items

\begin{enumerate} 

\item item A
\item item B
\item item C

\end{enumerate}
\newcommand{\NumberOfItems}{\value{enumi}}

The previous list contains \NumberOfItems\ items


\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that your question addresses the same problem as this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74595/count-and-use-the-number-of-items-in-advance Please tell us if it is the case. If so, we could mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @tohecz That question is specifically tailored for `itemize`.

Comment: Please, add a link to the other related question and add also the solution to your minimal example.

Comment: Are my changes what you asked for?

Comment: No, these aren't. However, you can exactly use `\getrefnumber{firstlist}` in place of your `\NumberOfItems` (requires the package `refcount`; `firstlist` is just the label assigned to the environment with `enumeratecount`) as I showed in my previous answer.

Comment: What's the problem with my solution in the previous answer? It does *exactly* what you're asking here.

Comment: Aha...I did not know the function "\getrefnumber{}". I agree, with that function I can use your former solution. Thanks ! : )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you plan to use this only for first level lists and don't plan to use the `enumitem` package for personalizing the environment, using a `\label` in the last item is sufficient.

However a general solution that allows for rearrangement of items without bothering with the position of `\label`, is compatible also with `enumitem` and also works for nested list can be the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{enumeratecount}[1]
  {\def\thisenumeratecountlabel{#1}\enumerate}
  {\edef\@currentlabel{\number\value{\@enumctr}}%
   \label{\thisenumeratecountlabel}\endenumerate}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The following list contains~\ref{firstlist} items, while
the nested list contains~\ref{innerlist}.

\begin{enumeratecount}{firstlist}
\item item A
\item item B
  \begin{enumeratecount}{innerlist}
  \item sub A
  \item sub B
  \end{enumeratecount}
\item item C
\end{enumeratecount}

The previous list contains \ref{firstlist} items, while the
inner list contains~\ref{innerlist}.

\end{document}
```

You just use `\begin{enumeratecount}{<label>}` for stating the label to be used (before or after the environment) for getting the number of items.

If you use `enumitem` you can even say

```
\begin{enumeratecount}{<label>}[<enumitem settings>]
```

so, for instance,

```
\begin{enumeratecount}{mylist}[label=\Alph*]
```

would work correctly (which wouldn't with the "simple method" outlined above and in Ulrike's answer).

---

The solution uses a couple of facts: a `\label` command refers to the current value of `\@currentlabel`, so before doing `\endenumerate` we define `\@currentlabel` to be the complete expansion of `\value{\@enumctr}`. The macro `\@enumctr` expands to `enumi`, `enumii`, `enumiii` or `enumiv` depending on the nesting level of the current `enumerate` environment; thus we're guaranteed to get the right number at all levels. Then we say `\label{\thisenumeratecountlabel}` that will set the label name to the original argument to `enumeratecount`. Locality of environments does the rest.

---

### An extension

Suppose we want to say "the following list contains 1 item" or "the following list contains 3 items", adding the "s" conditionally.

This can be done with the help of the `refcount` package.

```
\usepackage{refcount}
\newcommand{\addphrase}[3]{% #1 = label, #2 = text if number >1, #3 = text if number =1
  \ifnum\getrefnumber{#1}>1
    #2%
  \else
    #3%
  \fi}
```

So the text above can be generated by

```
the following list contains \ref{firstlist}~\addphrase{firstlist}{items}{item}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! How can I use \ref{firstlist} in a if-then-else decision? Something like \ifnumcomp{\ref{firstlist}{>}{1}{do this}{else, do that}

Comment: @EspenDonali I've added some code.

Comment: Thank again, but it is not exactly what i need. I need a new variable, made by \newcommand, with the value \ref{firstlist}, then I can use this variable in whatever commads from etoolbox.

Comment: @EspenDonali Please, make a new question, so that you can explain more clearly what you want, with some examples.

Comment: Sure : ), and thanks to both of you giving me answers thus far!

Answer (score 6):

In your example already `\ref` gives the correct output:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}

The following list contains \ref{a} items

\begin{enumerate} 

\item item A
\item item B
\item\label{a} item C

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not if the list is nested.

Comment: @egreg: I know. It also doesn't work if e.g. the numbering sheme is changed. That's why I wrote carefully "in the example ..." ;-). But I don't think that the question makes sense with nested lists. Would you write "The sub list of the second item hat 3 items?".

Answer (score 6):

**Q:** How can I count the number of items and store this number in a command by Q:\newcommand?

**A:** Add a counter to item

```
\let\olditem\item
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{
 \renewcommand{\item}{%
 \olditem%
 \stepcounter{mytempnumber}%
}}
```

As always one cannot redefine a macro recursive (that's why we need `\let`). I would like to recommend to use a counter for a number, not a macro.

**Q:** How can this be done, so that the value of this variable carries over to the next compilation where it can be available for "My conditional text" ?

**A:** Write it out! You can do this as value only, or as assignment:

```
\AtEndDocument{%
 \openoutputfile{\jobname.num}{number}
 \addtostream{number}{%%
 \noexpand\setcounter{mynumber}{\themytempnumber}} 
 \closeoutputstream{number}
}
```

We need to handle expansion carefully here, since everything is expanded when wrote to a file.

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{newfile}

\newoutputstream{number}

\newcounter{mynumber}
\newcounter{mytempnumber}

\let\olditem\item
\AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{
 \renewcommand{\item}{%
 \olditem%
 \stepcounter{mytempnumber}%
}}

\AtEndDocument{%
\openoutputfile{\jobname.num}{number}
\addtostream{number}{%%
 \noexpand\setcounter{mynumber}{\themytempnumber}} 
\closeoutputstream{number}
}

\AtBeginDocument%
{%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.num}{\input{\jobname.num}}{\message{NO \jobname.num rerun!}}%
}

\begin{document}

\themynumber% use as normal counter

\begin{enumerate} 
\item Issue A
\item Issue B
\item Issue C
\item 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I used `etoolbox` to hook into the `enumerate` environment and `newfile` to do the i/o stuff but more convenient. A interested user will notice, that the file `<main file name>.num` contents only one line of code: `\setcounter{mynumber}{4}`. So it's important to include the file before the usage of the counter.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough anwer! I will study it to see if I understand it, and then possibly implement it :)

Answer (score 2):

I used the `ifthen` package instead of `etoolbox` as I am more familiar with the former; there is likely a similar construct in the latter. Create a new counter, say `itemnum`. Set the value of the counter at then end of your enumerate command. Then a little trickery: take 1 from the counter, then `refstepcounter` it, which adds one back and allows you to save its value in a label. The `\ifthenelse` command uses its value and compares it to 1.

This, of course, takes 2 runs to take effect as does any `\label` & `\ref` combination.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twosided]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{itemnum}

\begin{document}

This report will addresses the following 
\ifthenelse{\ref{label:itemnum}=1}{issue}{issues}.


\begin{enumerate} 

\item Issue A
\item Issue B
\item Issue C
\setcounter{itemnum}{\value{enumi}}
\addtocounter{itemnum}{-1}
\refstepcounter{itemnum}\label{label:itemnum}

\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution was simple and straightforward, and I will use it.