# Count points per task

Tags: counters

We have a cooperate design template for exams. The disadvantage is, that we have to count the point for each task manually. My idea was to this automatically with counters.

What I am looking for:

```
\task{Java}
Hello World \points{2}
for-each \points{1}

\task{C++}
Bla bla \points{2}
Blub blub \points{4}

\task{Latex}
Foo foo \points{2}
bar bar \points{2}
```

I want to have a document which looks as follows after compiling:

---

## Java (3 Points)

Hello World (2 Points)

for-each (1 Point)

## C++ (6 Points)

Bla bla (2 Points)

Blub blub (4 Points)

## Latex (4 Points)

Foo foo (2 Points)

bar bar (2 Points)

---

My idea was to create a counter within the `\task`-command, and to use it with th `\addtocounter`-command within the `\points`-command. Actually, I did not manage to change the name for each counter dynamically.

Here is a MWE extracted from our template, were we are counting the points manually in the `\task``command:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,final]{scrartcl}

\newcounter{task}
\setcounter{task}{0}

\newcommand{\points}[1]{
    (#1~Points)
}

\newcommand{\task}[2]{
    \refstepcounter{task}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\LARGE\bf Task \arabic{task}}
    \end{flushleft}
    {\Large \textbf{#1}}
    \leavevmode\hfill ({#2}~Points)\\
}

\begin{document}

    \task{Java}{3}

    Hello World \points{2}

    for-each \points{1}

    \task{C++}{5}

    Bla bla \points{2}

    Blub blub \points{4}

    \task{Latex}{4}

    Foo foo \points{2}

    bar bar \points{2}

\end{document}
```

from: https://github.com/boldt/tex.stackexchange.com-186897/blob/master/exam.tex

Comment: That's one of the features provided by the excellent `exsheets` package.

Comment: @Jubobs not quite: `exsheets` doesn't provide a possibility to add points within the environment and have the sum printed in the title automatically. Until now you have to sum them up yourself. v0.14 will provide a possibility but it is not quite ready to be published (in a few days...)

Comment: @Jubobs I stand corrected: there *is* a possibility already

Comment: Now the question remains: can `exsheets` be used with the template (that we know nothing about...)

Comment: I played already with `exsheets` - it does not really fit. I will try to create a MWE from it, which has dozens of special features already :)

Comment: I added a MWE to my question.

Comment: You'll need two compilation passes unless you are happy with providing the various parts of a task as arguments so they can be processed and then typeset...

Comment: two compilation passes are fine for me! I found a solution, which you can find here: https://github.com/boldt/tex.stackexchange.com-186897/blob/155cc46e19168da875f8da3ac0339f4ece8e459b/exam.tex

Comment: @Dennis: See my updated answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: This looks really nice. Thanks for your dedication!

Comment: @Dennis: Alright, please give some feedback about strange behaviour. The handling of generating the file `\jobname.credits` definitely has to be improved, I know, I will gradually work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that user cslstr and I had the same idea ;-) I used a changed command from a former question of mine to write a label to the `.aux` file and read it later one using `\nameref*`.

The closing of a task would be much easier, if it would be inside an environment, however.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nameref}

\newcounter{task}
\setcounter{task}{0}


\newcounter{creditspertask}[task]
\setcounter{creditspertask}{0}%

\newcommand{\points}[1]{
    (#1~Points)
\addtocounter{creditspertask}{#1}%
}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WriteCreditsToFile}[1]{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{credits::\number\value{task}}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{#1}{}}
}% End of writing to AUX file
}%
\makeatother


\AtEndDocument{% For the last one only
\WriteCreditsToFile{\number\value{creditspertask}}%
}%

% 

\newcommand{\task}[1]{
  \WriteCreditsToFile{\number\value{creditspertask}}
    \refstepcounter{task}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\LARGE\bfseries Task \arabic{task}}
    \end{flushleft}
    {\Large \textbf{#1}}
    \leavevmode\hfill ({\nameref*{credits::\number\value{task}}}~Points)\\
}

\begin{document}

    \task{Java}

    Hello World \points{2}

    for-each \points{1}

    \task{C++}

    Bla bla \points{2}

    Blub blub \points{4}

    \task{Latex}

    Foo foo \points{2}

    bar bar \points{2}

\end{document}
```

**Edit** Updated version with `0.5` credits also possible and rudimentary `\listofcredits`

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{calculator}%
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{totcount}%
\usepackage{forloop}


\newcounter{task}
\setcounter{task}{0}


\xdef\TotalCredits{0}%
\xdef\TaskCredits{0}%
\xdef\SubCredits{0}%

\newcommand{\points}[2]{
\item #1   (#2~Points)
\ADD{\TaskCredits}{#2}{\SubCredits}%
\xdef\TaskCredits{\SubCredits}%
}%


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WriteCreditsToFile}[1]{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{credits::\number\value{task}}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{#1}{}}
}% End of writing to AUX file
}%
\makeatother
%

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{totalcredits}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{\TotalCredits}{}}
}
}
\makeatother


\newenvironment{Task}[1]{%
\xdef\TaskCredits{0}%
\xdef\SubCredits{0}%
\xdef\CreditsSoFar{0}%
    \refstepcounter{task}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\LARGE\bfseries Task \arabic{task}}
    \end{flushleft}
    {\Large \textbf{#1}}
    \leavevmode\hfill ({\nameref*{credits::\number\value{task}}}~Points)\\
    \begin{itemize} % Just for 'better' typography
}{% Close it
\end{itemize}
\WriteCreditsToFile{\TaskCredits}%
% Count all credits for the summary%
\ADD{\TotalCredits}{\TaskCredits}{\CreditsSoFar}%
\xdef\TotalCredits{\CreditsSoFar}%
}%


\regtotcounter{task}%

\makeatletter%

\newcounter{loop@@counter}%

\newcounter{totaltask@@counter}%
\newcommand{\listofcredits}{%
\setcounter{totaltask@@counter}{\number\totvalue{task}+1}%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Task number & Total credits & Achieved\tabularnewline
\hline
\forloop{loop@@counter}{1}{\number\value{loop@@counter} < \number\value{totaltask@@counter}}{%
Task \number\value{loop@@counter} & \nameref*{credits::\number\value{loop@@counter}} & \tabularnewline% 
} %
& \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{r}{Total:} & \nameref*{totalcredits} & \tabularnewline%
\end{tabular}
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listofcredits
\newpage

    \begin{Task}{Java}
      \points{Hello World}{2.5}
      \points{for-each}{2}
  \end{Task}%

    \begin{Task}{C++}
     \points{Bla bla}{2}
     \points{blub blub}{4}
    \end{Task}

    \begin{Task}{Latex}
     \points{Foo}{2}
     \points{bar}{2}
    \end{Task}

\begin{Task}{Fortran54} % ;-)
  \points{Write a Fortran 54 code to  \LaTeX ;-)}{100}
  \points{Write a Babbage machine  code to replace \LaTeX ;-)}{1000}
\end{Task}




\end{document}
```

**Edit** New version

Since `\nameref*{}` is not expandable, another approach must be used for summing up etc. The new version writes the total credits per task into an external file which is read afterwards again to complete the total task credits at the top position and for the `\listoftask` commands.

The code

- works if all tasks are written to the `\jobname.credits` file
- works if there are true numbers and not mathematical expressions for credits
- requires **two** runs
- does not work for section wise task numbering
- fails if another task is added somewhere, because the writing of `\jobname.credits` is done only during the first run. In this case remove `\jobname.aux` and `\jobname.credits`, then run again twice.

Of course, I could not check everything and the output formatting etc. is just a proposition, where I borrowed code from the OP answer, which was a direct reaction on my first version, so I think, this is ok.

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{calculator}
\usepackage{morewrites}

\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{forloop}%
\usepackage{totcount}%
\usepackage{ifthen}%
\usepackage{tikz}%




\newwrite\CreditsFileHandle%

\newcounter{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}%
\newcommand{\WriteFileThreshold}{2}%


\newcommand{\CounterValue}[1]{%
\ifltxcounter{#1}{%
\number\value{#1}}{%
#1}%
}%



\xdef\tempsum{0}%
\xdef\othersum{0}%

\newcommand{\sumup}[1]{%
\ADD{\tempsum}{#1}{\othersum}%
\xdef\tempsum{\othersum}%
}%


\makeatletter

\newcommand{\WriteToFile}[2][\CreditsFileHandle]{%
\immediate\write#1{%
#2%
}%
}%


\newcommand{\CloseForReading}[1][\CreditsFileHandle]{%
\immediate\closein#1%
}%

\newcommand{\CloseForWriting}[1][\CreditsFileHandle]{%
\immediate\closeout#1%
}%


\newcommand{\OpenForReading}[2][\CreditsFileHandle]{%
\immediate\openin#1=#2%
}%

\newcommand{\OpenForWriting}[2][\CreditsFileHandle]{%
\immediate\openout#1=#2%
}%





\xdef\@@TotalCreditsValue{1}%
\listgadd{\CreditsSumList}{}%

\newcommand{\DisplayQuestionAndCredits}[2]{%
\item #1 (\DisplayCredits{#2})% 
\listgadd{\CreditsSumList}{#2}%
}%


\newcommand{\CreditsName}{point}%
\newcommand{\CreditsNamePlural}{points}%

\newcommand{\DisplayCredits}[1]{%
\pgfmathequal{#1}{1}%
\ifnumequal{\pgfmathresult}{1}{
#1 \CreditsName%
}{%
#1 \CreditsNamePlural%
}%%
}%



\newcommand{\ReadCreditValueWithSumUp}[2][\CreditsFileHandle]{%
\ReadCreditValue[#1]{#2}%
#2\sumup{#2}%
}%

\newcommand{\ReadCreditValue}[2][\CreditsFileHandle]{%
\read#1 to #2% Read in from file
}%



\newcounter{task}%
\newenvironment{Task}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{task}%
\ifnumequal{\CounterValue{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}}{\WriteFileThreshold}{%
\ReadCreditValue{\@@TotalCreditsValue}%
}{}%
\begin{flushleft}
{\Large \textbf{Task} \textbf{\thetask} -- \textbf{#1}}%%
\hfill  \fcolorbox{black}{yellow}{\DisplayCredits{\@@TotalCreditsValue}}% 
\end{flushleft}%
\begin{itemize}
}{%
\end{itemize}
\ifnumless{\CounterValue{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}}{\WriteFileThreshold}{%
%Do only sum up when not in final output mode 
\sumuplist{\CreditsSumList}%
\WriteToFile{\tempsum}%
}{% No, the number of runs is greater than zero, so ... do nothing
}% 
\xdef\CreditsSumList{}%
}%



\newcommand{\sumuplist}[1]{%
\xdef\tempsum{0}%
\forlistloop{\sumup}{#1}%
}%




\regtotcounter{task}%
\newcounter{totaltask@@counter}%
\newcounter{last@@counter}%
\newcounter{loop@@counter}%


\newcommand{\mk}[1]{%
}%





\newcommand{\listoftasks}{%
\gdef\CurrentSumValue{0.0}%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.credits}{%
\CloseForWriting% 
\OpenForReading{\jobname.credits}%
\begin{center}
  \setcounter{totaltask@@counter}{\number\totvalue{task}+1}%
  \setcounter{last@@counter}{\number\totvalue{task}}%
  \Huge \textbf{List of Tasks}\normalsize 

  \vspace{\baselineskip} %
  \begin{tabular}{|c||r|c|c|}
    \hline
    Task number & Total credits & Achieved credits\\
    \hline
    \hline
    \forloop{loop@@counter}{1}{\CounterValue{loop@@counter} < \CounterValue{totaltask@@counter}}{%
      \CounterValue{loop@@counter} & %
      \ReadCreditValueWithSumUp{\CurrentSumValue}% Do not delete that % character before!
      & %
      \ifnum\number\value{loop@@counter}<\CounterValue{last@@counter}%  %\number\value{last@@counter}
      \tabularnewline\hline
      \fi%
      \xdef\CurrentSumValue{0}%
    }%
    \tabularnewline%
    \hline%
    \hline\hline%
    \multicolumn{1}{|l||}{Total:} & \tempsum & \tabularnewline%
    \hline%
  \end{tabular}%
\end{center}%
\newpage% Well, later an \clearpage?
% Now close the handle than open it again for reading total values in the individual tasks to complete
%the values.
\CloseForReading%
\OpenForReading{\jobname.credits}%
}{}%
}%



\AtBeginDocument{%
  \refstepcounter{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}%
  \ifnumequal{\CounterValue{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}}{\WriteFileThreshold}{%
    \CloseForWriting%
    \OpenForReading{\jobname.credits}%
  }{%
    \OpenForWriting{\jobname.credits}%
  }%
}%

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\CreditsFileHandle%
  \ifnumequal{\CounterValue{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}}{\WriteFileThreshold}{%
    \setcounter{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}{1}}{}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\setcounter{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}{\number\value{NumberOfLaTeXRuns}}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\listoftasks


\begin{Task}{Java}%
\DisplayQuestionAndCredits{Hello World in Java}{10}%
\end{Task}%


\begin{Task}{C++}%
\DisplayQuestionAndCredits{Virtual methods}{10}%
\DisplayQuestionAndCredits{Operator overloading}{15}%
\end{Task}%

\begin{Task}{\LaTeXe}
\DisplayQuestionAndCredits{Reproduce this document ;-)}{2000}%
\DisplayQuestionAndCredits{Are there better sites than TeX.SX?}{10000.14159}%
\end{Task}


\begin{Task}{Fortran 54}
\DisplayQuestionAndCredits{Write a Fortran program better than \LaTeXe }{100}
\DisplayQuestionAndCredits{Write code for a Babbage machine with objects}{200}
\end{Task}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did something like this (with an environment) 5 min ago. (see comment under my question and under cslstr's answer)

Comment: Well, it was not working then? I am just working on the environment version...

Comment: It looks like my env-version works :)

Comment: @Dennis: So all efforts by us were useless ;-)

Comment: Not really, I just found a way (quite similar to yours) in the same moment. You're versions are "similar", but different. I am still learning from you guys!

Comment: An appropriate question: is there a simple way to print an overview table from the lables like: Task 1: 2 Points, Task 2: 4 Points, etc...

Comment: @Dennis: That should be possible, I will see.

Comment: I can't give half point (e.g., 0.5 or 1.5), which crashes the counter...

Comment: @Dennis: I updated the code also possible for `0.5` credits and a `\listofcredits` command ;-)

Comment: @Dennis: Alright (but not so fast... I am a little unsatisfied with the `\listofcredits` table so far. I will provide another solution to that, but not now ;-))

Comment: I adjusted your code. Now it fits perfect in our template. I will provide my `\listofcredits` table soon.

Comment: @Dennis: I am looking forward to see your version, as I had no time to improve my code so far.

Comment: @Chistian: I just updated your code with my `\listoftasks`. I Also added `\printpoints` to handle "1 point". Unfortunately this does not work with `\nameref`. Maybe you can have a look on that, so "1 point" can be seen in the `\listoftasks` as well.

Comment: @Dennis: I appreciate your support, but I do not like my answers to be changed, as long as there no serious errors in it. Please add your improvements as self-answer or in your OP

Comment: I just added a self-answer with my improvements. Maybe you can have a look on the `\nameref` issue.

Comment: @Dennis: I will do later on

Answer (score 5):

With a current version of [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) the package provides a possibility for this. `exsheets` has a command `\addpoints` that prints *and* saves the points for the current `{question}` environment. The sum of points of a question is available as a *question property* named `points` that can be retrieved via `\GetQuestionProperty{<property>}{<question ID>}`

In combination with `exsheets`' possibility to create custom headings instances and the command `\CurrentQuestionID` it is possible to define a heading type that prints the sum of the points saved with `\addpoints` in the `{question}` body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

% custom headings instance:
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{custom}{default}{
  % write the sum of points after the title of the question:
  title-post-code =
    \bfseries~(\GetQuestionProperty{points}{\CurrentQuestionID} Points) ,
  % print the title:
  attach = { main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) }
}

% use the newly defined heading instance:
\SetupExSheets{
  headings = custom ,
  points/name = Point/s
}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[name=Java]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Hello World (\addpoints{2})
    \item for-each (\addpoints{1})
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[name=C++]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Bla bla (\addpoints{2})
    \item Blub blub (\addpoints{4})
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[name=\LaTeX]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo foo (\addpoints{2})
    \item bar bar (\addpoints{2})
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The spacing looks a bit weird but that could be adjusted, e.g., by adding `below  = .5\baselineskip` to the definition of the headings instance.

---

With an even more recent version of `exsheets` (v0.14 2014/06/28, it's already on CTAN and in TeX Live 2014) it is possible with a little bit of effort to define a grading table. The trick is to use *question properties*. For this I use the properties `subtitle`, `counter` and `points` that are already defined by `exsheets`. The commands `\GetQuestionProperty{<property>}{<question id>}` and `\ForEachQuestion{<code where #1 refers to the question id>`} I loop through all questions and retrieve the needed data:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}[2014/06/28]

% a custom headings instance that uses the `subtitle' property:
\DeclareInstance{exsheets-heading}{custom}{default}{
  subtitle-format = \bfseries ,
  subtitle-post-code =
    \bfseries~(\GetQuestionProperty{points}{\CurrentQuestionID} Points) ,
  join = {
    title[r,B]number[l,B](.333em,0pt) ;
    title[r,B]subtitle[l,B](.333em,0pt)
  } ,
  attach = { main[l,vc]title[l,vc](0pt,0pt) } ,
  below  = .5\baselineskip
}

% use the new instance, other settings:
\SetupExSheets{
  question/name = Task ,
  headings = custom ,
  points/name = Point/s
}

% define a grading table that retrieves subtitles and points:
\newcommand*\gradingtable{%
  \begin{tabular}{|l|*{3}{c|}c|}\hline
    Task &
      \ForEachQuestion{%
        \GetQuestionProperty{counter}{##1}
        \GetQuestionProperty{subtitle}{##1}\iflastquestion{}{&}%
      }
      & Total \\ \hline
    Points   &
     \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{##1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} &
       \pointssum* \\ \hline
    Reached  &
      \ForEachQuestion{\iflastquestion{}{&}} &
      \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \gradingtable
\end{center}

\begin{question}[subtitle=Java,ID=Java]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Hello World (\addpoints{2})
    \item for-each (\addpoints{1})
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle=C++,ID=C++]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Bla bla (\addpoints{2})
    \item Blub blub (\addpoints{4})
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}

\begin{question}[subtitle=\LaTeX,ID=LaTeX]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo foo (\addpoints{2})
    \item bar bar (\addpoints{2})
  \end{enumerate}
\end{question}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This answer leverages the existing `\label`ing capabilities to write the totals out to the aux file.  Then the label value can be used with `\ref{}` where needed.

As mentioned in the comments, two passes will be required for it to work properly.

Also note, `\AtEndDocument` is used to call the final `\closetask` command.  This could maybe cause problems if you don't ever use `\task`... this could be either put into a conditional with a flag that is set on first use of `\task`, or `\task` could be turned into an environment to use `\begin{task}...\end{task}`.  Using an environment may actually make more sense semantically, though sub-tasks would not be supported out of the box.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,final]{scrartcl}

\newcounter{task}
\setcounter{task}{0}

% Create a new counter to keep track of points for each task
\newcounter{taskpoints}
\setcounter{taskpoints}{0}

% Create \pointslabel{}{} for saving the points total as a label
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
\newcommand{\pointslabel}[2]{%
   \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{#2}{#1}{}} }%
   \hypertarget{#1}{#2}
}}{%
\newcommand{\pointslabel}[2]{%
\protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{#2}{}}}}}
\makeatother

% Call \closetask at the end of each task, before beginning next task
\def\closetask{%
\pointslabel{taskpoints:\arabic{task}}{\arabic{taskpoints}}}
\AtEndDocument{\closetask} % Automatically close the last task

% Reset the taskpoints whenever the task increments
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{taskpoints}{task}


\newcommand{\points}[1]{
    % Add #1 points to the taskpoints counter
    \addtocounter{taskpoints}{#1}
    (#1~Points)
}

\newcommand{\task}[1]{
    \closetask % Close out previous task
    \refstepcounter{task}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\LARGE\bf Task \arabic{task}}
    \end{flushleft}
    {\Large \textbf{#1}}
    % Addition of points with \ref to label
    \leavevmode\hfill (\ref{taskpoints:\arabic{task}} Points)\\
}

\begin{document}

    \task{Java}

    Hello World \points{2}

    for-each \points{1}

    \task{C++}

    Bla bla \points{2}

    Blub blub \points{4}

    \task{Latex}

    Foo foo \points{2}

    bar bar \points{2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just worked on a solution based on this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74595/count-and-use-the-number-of-items-in-advance which you can find here https://github.com/boldt/tex.stackexchange.com-186897/blob/155cc46e19168da875f8da3ac0339f4ece8e459b/exam.tex For This, I am using an environment.

Answer (score 1):

This improved version is based on the answer by Christian Huper:

- it has a more fancy table to print the list of tasks (fixed line wrapping in the table)
- it prints "1 point" instead of "1 points"

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{calculator}%
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{totcount}%
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{task}
\setcounter{task}{0}


\xdef\TotalCredits{0}%
\xdef\TaskCredits{0}%
\xdef\SubCredits{0}%

\newcommand{\printpoints}[1]{#1~\pgfmathequal{#1}{1}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1 point\else points\fi}

\newcommand{\points}[2]{
\item #1 (\printpoints{#2})
\ADD{\TaskCredits}{#2}{\SubCredits}%
\xdef\TaskCredits{\SubCredits}%
}%


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\WriteCreditsToFile}[1]{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{credits::\number\value{task}}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{#1}{}}
}% End of writing to AUX file
}%
\makeatother
%

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{%
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
\string\newlabel{totalcredits}{{\thesection}{\thepage}{\TotalCredits}{}}
}
}
\makeatother


\newenvironment{Task}[1]{%
\xdef\TaskCredits{0}%
\xdef\SubCredits{0}%
\xdef\CreditsSoFar{0}%
    \refstepcounter{task}
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\LARGE\bfseries Task \arabic{task}}
    \end{flushleft}
    {\Large \textbf{#1}}
    \leavevmode\hfill (\nameref*{credits::\number\value{task}}~Points)\\
    \begin{itemize} % Just for 'better' typography
}{% Close it
\end{itemize}
\WriteCreditsToFile{\TaskCredits}%
% Count all credits for the summary%
\ADD{\TotalCredits}{\TaskCredits}{\CreditsSoFar}%
\xdef\TotalCredits{\CreditsSoFar}%
}%


\regtotcounter{task}%

\makeatletter%

\newcounter{loop@@counter}%

\newcounter{totaltask@@counter}%
\newcounter{last@@counter}%

\newcommand{\listoftasks}{%
    \begin{center}
    \setcounter{totaltask@@counter}{\number\totvalue{task}+1}%
    \setcounter{last@@counter}{\number\totvalue{task}}%
    \begin{tabular}{|c||r|c|c|}
    \hline
    Task number & Total credits & Achieved credits\\
    \hline
    \hline
    \forloop{loop@@counter}{1}{\number\value{loop@@counter} < \number\value{totaltask@@counter}}{
        \number\value{loop@@counter} & \nameref*{credits::\number\value{loop@@counter}} Points &
        \ifnum\number\value{loop@@counter}<\number\value{last@@counter}
            \tabularnewline\hline
        \fi
    }
    \tabularnewline
    \hline
    \hline\hline
    Total: & \nameref*{totalcredits} Points & \tabularnewline%
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
}%

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\listoftasks
\newpage

    \begin{Task}{Java}
      \points{Hello World}{1}
  \end{Task}%

    \begin{Task}{C++}
      \points{for-each}{0.5}
     \points{blub blub}{0.5}
    \end{Task}

    \begin{Task}{Latex}
     \points{Foo}{2}
     \points{bar}{2}
    \end{Task}

\begin{Task}{Fortran54} % ;-)
  \points{Write a Fortran 54 code to  \LaTeX ;-)}{100}
  \points{Write a Babbage machine  code to replace \LaTeX ;-)}{1000}
\end{Task}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but you mentioned an issue with `\nameref`?

Comment: Now I know what you mean: The problem is that `\nameref*` is not expandable, in this case `\pgfmathresult` contains the command `\nameref*` but not the reference value. I am working on different solution, but it takes time!