# Why can't I expand \ref*{} as a string?

Tags: hyperref, xstring

In the following code, if you change `\def` to `\edef` the code crashes.  Nor can you perform normal string operations or tests.  Removing `hyperref` (and replacing `\ref*` with `\ref`) works fine with `\edef`.  Is there a way to convert `\ref*` into a usable string?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{first}

\def\temp{\ref*{first}}\noindent Section = \temp

%\edef\temp{\ref*{first}}\noindent Section = \temp

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by `usable string`? From the [tag:xstring] I'm guessing there is more to this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\ref` can't go in `\edef` no matter whether you load `hyperref` or not. The code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{first}

\edef\temp{\ref{first}}\noindent Section = \temp

\end{document}
```

stops with

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.5 ...\temp{\ref{first}}\noindent Section = \temp
```

Only if the label has already been written to the `.aux` file the `\edef` works. In any case, no command with a `*`-variant or optional argument can go in `\edef` (unless it's defined in a special way with `xparse`).

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{first}

\edef\temp{\getrefnumber{first}}\noindent Section = \temp

\end{document}
```

On the first run after the `\label` has been added, `\temp` will expand to `0`. Upon rerunning LaTeX, you'll get the correct reference.

Comment: While it wasn't part of the problem definition, it seems I still can't use \StrCut to split, say, 1.1 into substrings 1 and 1.

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, `xstring` command can't be used in `\edef`. Can you state your problem more clearly?

Comment: Aha!  \detokenize\temp works in \StrCut

Comment: And here is where I used it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208958/how-to-change-the-appearance-of-ref-depending-on-where-its-called-relative-to/209218#209218

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether my answer perfectly answers the question, but the problem that I had seems very related, so I am posting my answer anyway -- hopefully it is useful to someone.

I had to perform a computation with a reference, i.e., to add some number to the value of, e.g., `\ref{some-label}`. However, the result of `\ref{some-label}` was not recognized as number (although the output, if printed, is a number). Thus, I was not able to use it as a number, getting a `! Missing number, treated as zero.` error message. Instead, using `\getrefnumber{some-label}` solves the problem, i.e., then computations can be done.

Comment: The problem is similar (calculations require expandable arguments) and so is the solution (use [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount)'s `\getrefnumber`). Therefore, it doesn't seem to add anything new to this post is not already covered.