# How to replace \zpageref to page number in \edef

Tags: cross-referencing, expansion, zref

I want to dump positions of objects to an external file with `zref` package.
I can dump `zposx` and `zposy`, but not be able to dump `zrefpage`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}

\begin{document}

ABC \zlabel{page}\zsavepos{pos}
page: \zpageref{page}

\edef\temp{page \zpageref{page} position \zposx{pos} \zposy{pos}}

\newwrite\writer
\openout\writer=position.pos\relax
\write\writer{\temp}
\closeout\writer

\end{document}
```

Dumped position.pos file after 2 compilations:

```
page \zpageref {page} position 11430063 42091806
```

`\zpageref` is still there.

How to replace `\zpageref{page}` by its page number?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209195/143504, I realize that probably `\zref` cannot be used in `\edef` also.

By reading `zref` document, I figured out how to get the number.
Use `zref@extractdefault` to get the page number, but not `zpageref`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[user,savepos]{zref}


\begin{document}

ABC \zlabel{page-label}\zsavepos{pos}

\makeatletter
\edef\temp{page \zref@extractdefault{page-label}{page}{0} position \zposx{pos} \zposy{pos}}
\makeatother

\newwrite\writer
\openout\writer=position.pos\relax
\write\writer{\temp}
\closeout\writer

\end{document}
```

And the `position.pos`:

```
page 1 position 11430063 42091806
```