# Reference and &-character in text along path in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-decorations

I would like to use the &-symbol and reference (to sections) in the texts that are circled around the inner point but whenever I try to do this, the document compiles to infinity.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [ europeanresistors ]{ circuitikz }
\usepackage{tikz, pgfornament, tikzrput}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows,decorations, decorations.text}
    \usepackage[textwidth=5cm,textheight=5cm,right=2.5cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{fix-cm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[double distance=10mm](0,0) circle (2.3cm);
\node at (0,0,0,0) {This \& that \ref{sec:intro}};
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, reverse path,text align=center, text={||Inner Ring 1 }}}] (-36:2.3cm) arc (-36:216:2.3cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, text align=right, text={||Inner Ring 2}}}] (-36:2.3cm) arc (-36:370:2.3cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, text align=right, text={||Inner Ring 3}}}] (-36:2.3cm) arc (-36:220:2.3cm);
%Not working:
%\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, text align=right, text={||This \& that \ref{sec:intro} 3}}}] (-36:2.3cm) arc (-36:220:2.3cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{This is a circle} 
\label{fig:circle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This has really nothing to do with `circuitikz`. If you remove the `\usepackage{circuitikz}`, the result and the problem (which I don't know how to solve, sorry...) it's exactly the same. Please, try to reduce the thing to a *minimal* example. I'll fix the tags.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

There're two issues in the expression

```tex
This \& that \ref{sec:intro} 3
```

The first is the ampersand. The fix is easy, enclose it with braces:

```tex
This {\&} that \ref{sec:intro} 3
```

The second is the `\ref`. A workaround would be to convert the section number to a simple string. Following [Why can't I expand \ref*{} as a string?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209195/316068), you can try:

```
\edef\introsectionnumber{\getrefnumber{sec:intro}}
```

before

```tex
This {\&} that \introsectionnumber{} 3
```

So this should work:

```tex
% working:
\edef\introsectionnumber{\getrefnumber{sec:intro}}
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, text align=right, text={||This {\&} that \introsectionnumber{}  3}}}] (-36:2.3cm) arc (-36:220:2.3cm);
```

Comment: Great, this works fine. But I guess there is no possibility to keep the hyperlink reference to the section?

Comment: @JuliePRE Sorry, I'm afraid this is beyond my skills.

Comment: @JuliePRE that is another question. You should be able to prepare a very short minimum example for that;  go ahead and post it! (The author of hyperref is often around; make an easy-to-answer question and maybe she knows how to solve it).