# How to count the number of items in enumerate when nesting and [resume]

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate, enumitem

As question [Count and use the number of items in advance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74595/count-and-use-the-number-of-items-in-advance) mentioned, I have the same demand, but mine is more advanced.

Here I have some enumerates, some of them begin with `[resume]` paramater, some of them have nested enumerate. I want to compute the number of the first level items of each enumerate. For example

[image]

I wrote codes below:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{totalitems}
\newcounter{beginitems}
\newcounter{enditems}
\let\@numerate\enumerate

\def\enumerate{%
    \setcounter{beginitems}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \@numerate
}
\let\end@numerate\endenumerate
\def\endenumerate{
    \end@numerate%
    \setcounter{enditems}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \setcounter{totalitems}{\numexpr \c@enditems - \c@beginitems \relax}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \item two
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item three
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item a nested enumerate
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one 
        \item two 
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems
    
\end{document}
```

it produced:

[image]

As we can see there are some things goes wrong

1. When there is nested enumerate, the `beginitems` counter is wrong
2. When there is no `[resume]` paramater, the `beginitems` counter didn't been reset to 0.

Where should I change to reach my demand?

Comment: You need to postpone `\setcounter{beginitems}{\arabic{enumi}}` to after the `enumerate` environment was initiated, so essentially after `\begin{enumerate}` or `\begin{enumerate}[resume]`.

Comment: yeah, I tried to put it after `\@numerate`, but this would lead an error: I can't add optional paramaters included `[resume]` of `enumerate` evironment,

Comment: It might be easier to use the internal counters: enumi, enumii, enumiii and enumiv.  You can also use \theenumi etc.  Enumitem still uses them.  It also adds a count for a series name: `\csname enitdp@`<name>`\endcsname`.

Comment: REALY Thanks to @JohnKormylo !! I solve this question with your hint.  I found the `\enit@depth` cotrol sequence to test which level is. Could you please write an answer? I'll give you the acceptance, or not I'll update my question and accept @Jasper's answer.Also a huge thanks for @JasperHabicht .

Comment: I assumed this was just a test document to figure out how to get the counters.  Go ahead and give it to Jasper.

Comment: Since Jasper didn't reply for a period of time, I'll answer my question myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THANKS FOR @JohnKormylo and @JasperHabicht**

### method from @JasperHabicht

I found a control sequence `\enit@depth` which show the enumerate depth. So I can use `\if` to test if I'm in the first level, like this:

```latex
\renewcommand{\enumerate}[1][]{%
    \@numerate[#1]%
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne
        \setcounter{beginitems}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \fi
}
\renewcommand{\endenumerate}{
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne
        \setcounter{enditems}{\arabic{enumi}}
        \setcounter{totalitems}{\numexpr \c@enditems - \c@beginitems \relax}
    \fi
    \end@numerate%
}
```

If we do this, when we aren't in the first level, `\setcounter`s won't work. The whole codes are:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{totalitems}
\newcounter{beginitems}
\newcounter{enditems}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\@numerate}{\enumerate}
\LetLtxMacro{\end@numerate}{\endenumerate}

\renewcommand{\enumerate}[1][]{%
    \@numerate[#1]%
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne
        \setcounter{beginitems}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \fi
}
\renewcommand{\endenumerate}{
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne
        \setcounter{enditems}{\arabic{enumi}}
        \setcounter{totalitems}{\numexpr \c@enditems - \c@beginitems \relax}
    \fi
    \end@numerate%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \item two
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item three
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item a nested enumerate
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one 
        \item two 
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

### my new method

In this method, I renew the `\item` command, let the conter plus 1 when `\item` appears in the top level:

1. first, we create a newif `\ifenum` to test if we are in the top level, we create a counter and save the macros:

```latex
\newif\ifenum
\newcounter{totalitems}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\@numerate}{\enumerate}
\LetLtxMacro{\end@numerate}{\endenumerate}
\LetLtxMacro{\it@m}{\item}
```

2. use `xparse` to renew the `\item` command, when this `\item` is in the top level, step the counter `totalitems`. Also we can let it have some new features, like `\item*` for not count, `\item[<paramater>]` for a user-defined label as the previous definition but also count, `\item*[paramater]` for a user-defined label without count:

```latex
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\item}{ s o }{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\it@m}{\it@m[#2]}  
    \ifenum
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{\addtocounter{totalitems}{-1}}%
        \stepcounter{totalitems}
    \fi
}
```

3. Then we judge when should we true the `\ifenum`: after `\begin{enumerate}`, we test if we are in the top level, if true, set `totalitems` to 0, and set `\enumtrue`, if not, set `\enumfalse`; before `\end{enumerate}` act oppositely. It doesn't matter when nested list appears, because `\ifenum` always truns false when the second or deeper level begins.

```latex
\renewcommand{\enumerate}[1][]{%
    \@numerate[#1]
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne
        \setcounter{totalitems}{0}
        \enumtrue
    \else
        \enumfalse
    \fi
}
\renewcommand{\endenumerate}{
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne 
        \enumfalse
    \else
        \enumtrue
    \fi
    \end@numerate%
}
```

Now we can get the number of the top level items:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newif\ifenum
\makeatletter
\newcounter{totalitems}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\@numerate}{\enumerate}
\LetLtxMacro{\end@numerate}{\endenumerate}
\LetLtxMacro{\it@m}{\item}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\item}{ s o }{
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\it@m}{\it@m[#2]}
    \ifenum
        \IfBooleanT{#1}{\addtocounter{totalitems}{-1}}%
        \stepcounter{totalitems}
    \fi
}

\renewcommand{\enumerate}[1][]{%
    \@numerate[#1]
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne
        \setcounter{totalitems}{0}
        \enumtrue
    \else
        \enumfalse
    \fi
}
\renewcommand{\endenumerate}{
    \ifnum\enit@depth=\@ne 
        \enumfalse
    \else
        \enumtrue
    \fi
    \end@numerate%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \item two
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item three
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item a nested enumerate
            \item* a star nest
        \end{enumerate}
        \item item after nested
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item* a star version 
        \item[paramater] the only item which is counted
        \item*[paramater] a star version with paramater
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to postpone `\setcounter{beginitems}{\arabic{enumi}}` to after the `enumerate` environment was initiated, so essentially after `\begin{enumerate}` or `\begin{enumerate}[resume]` respectively. You need to take into account that `\begin{environment}` may have one optional argument.

I am not totally sure, but I think, using `\LetLtxMacro` instead of a plain `\let` and `\renewcommand` instead of `\def` is a bit more secure here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{totalitems}
\newcounter{beginitems}
\newcounter{enditems}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\@numerate}{\enumerate}
\LetLtxMacro{\end@numerate}{\endenumerate}

\renewcommand{\enumerate}[1][]{%
    \@numerate[#1]%
    \setcounter{beginitems}{\arabic{enumi}}
}
\renewcommand{\endenumerate}{
    \end@numerate%
    \setcounter{enditems}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \setcounter{totalitems}{\numexpr \c@enditems - \c@beginitems \relax}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \item two
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems

    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item three
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item a nested enumerate
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one 
        \item two 
    \end{enumerate}
    total = \thetotalitems, begin = \thebeginitems, end = \theenditems
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, you still may have the problem that the counters are affected every time, an `enumerate` environment starts, which may cause wrong results when `enumerate` environments are nested. I did not test this thouroughly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was always thinking how to check if the optional paramater is `resume` or not. You saved me from this question. maybe I have to read some books to find what happens when nesting.

Comment: Since the `enumerate` environment (if used with the `enumitem`) package only can take exactly one optional parameter (at least as far as I know), this will more or less cover all use cases.

Comment: Ah, I know why counters after (a) went wrong. When we use the second level of `enumerate`, `\begin` of second level and `\end` of first level determined the value of `beginitems` and `enditems`. Both of them are 3, so we got a 0 of `totalitems`.

Comment: I wrote an answer which reach my demand, thanks for your answer :)