# Getting enumerate counter value

Tags: counters

I have large lists of the kind

```
There are N values:

\begin{enumerate}
\item item1
\item item2
...
\item itemN
```

How can I replace "N" in the first line of text by a counter that would automatically show N such as in

```
There are \readcounter{enumlist} values:

\begin{enumerate}
\item item1
\item item2
...
\item itemN
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: See the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74597/110998

Comment: Thank you @gernot, the solution provided (putting a \label{} for the last item and using \ref{}) works very well but has two drawback: \ref{} produces a link to the last item of the enumerate + gets the color of an hyperlink. Is there a way to locally disable this.

Comment: @leparc Have you seen the discussion below the answer that I linked to? It seems to be exactly your issue, and `\ref*` seems to be the solution.

Comment: @gernot, thank you so much, I read it too fast and jumped on the `\ref` solution when `\ref*` is what I need.