# Get number of elements in enumerate

Tags: enumerate, programming

Suppose, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
We have totally 7 columns, describing the user:
\begin{enumerate}
\item ID --- users.name
\item Forename --- users\_profiles.first\_name
\item Surname --- users\_profiles.last\_name
\item Email --- users.mail
\item Primary Service --- services.name
\item Start date --- FROM\_UNIXTIME(users.created)
\item Employment Status --- users\_profiles.employment\_status
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Producing this document:

[image]

Is it possible to set the value 7 automatically, depending upon number of elements in the list? The problem is, that it resides before the list.

Comment: Related: [How to make enumerate items align at left margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29322/5764) - it uses a similar technique to Alan's answer to adjust the width of the label.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just put a label after the last item and refer to that in the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
We have \ref{last} columns, describing the user:
\begin{enumerate}
\item ID --- users.name
\item Forename --- users\_profiles.first\_name
\item Surname --- users\_profiles.last\_name
\item Email --- users.mail
\item Primary Service --- services.name
\item Start date --- FROM\_UNIXTIME(users.created)
\item Employment Status --- users\_profiles.employment\_status \label{last}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this does require a second run of the file, but it's vanishingly rare that there's no second (or further) run.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yeah, second run is pretty annoying. Does anybody know, how to get rid of it?

Comment: There's no way to avoid this, but it's likely that your document has other references that need to be reconciled anyway.  If you're worried about forgetting to run latex the required number of times, there are [Tools for automating document compilation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64/2693). For TeXLive installations, `latexmk` is good; MikTeX also has `texify` and there is also the relatively new, but very powerful `arara`.

Comment: @AlanMunn your variant works perfectly, when there is only 1 list. But what to do, when we have several lists? When I tried your code, it gives the number of elements in the last list everywhere.

Comment: @user4035 Since the system uses labels, you need a unique label for each list you want to do this with.  So if you have *n* lists, you need *n* distinct "last" labels, which you could label `last1`, `last2` etc. or alternatively use more descriptive labels that identify the lists themselves (`UserList-last`, `FunctionAList-last` etc).

Answer (score 6):

The `\label`-`\ref` mechanism is the way to go for this kind of applications; in this case some tweaking is necessary for ensuring that we get a plain number.

I'll present two possibilities. In both I use `\numberstringnum` from `fmtcount` to produce the number in words, which is better style.

### Recommended form

We use a `refenumerate` environment that has a label (an arbitrary string) as argument, to be used as argument of `\getenumcount`, which produces the number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,fmtcount,refcount}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{refenumerate}{m}
 {\begin{enumerate}}
 {\edef\@currentlabel{\arabic{\@enumctr}}\label{#1}\end{enumerate}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\getenumcount}[1]{\numberstringnum{\getrefnumber{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Recommended form}

We have \getenumcount{profile} columns, describing the user:
\begin{refenumerate}{profile}
\item ID --- users.name
\item Forename --- users\_profiles.first\_name
\item Surname --- users\_profiles.last\_name
\item Email --- users.mail
\item Primary Service --- services.name
\item Start date --- FROM\_UNIXTIME(users.created)
\item Employment Status --- users\_profiles.employment\_status
\end{refenumerate}
```

#### Pros

The `refenumerate` environment can be used at any nesting level

#### Cons

It requires two runs of LaTeX. This is actually not a big deal, because it's quite rare that one run suffice (think to the table of contents, or any cross reference).

[image]

### Not recommended form

We use a `getreference` environment that encloses all code from the start of the paragraph with the reference up to the `enumerate` environment we want to count the items of.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmtcount,environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{getreference}
 {\let\latex@label\label\let\label\@gobble\global\let\printnumber\relax
  \setbox0=\vbox{\@tempswafalse\if@nobreak\@tempswatrue\fi
    \BODY\xdef\printnumber{\noexpand\numberstringnum{\number\value{enumi}}}
    \if@tempswa\aftergroup\@afterheading\fi
  }%
  \let\label\latex@label
  \BODY}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section*{Not recommended form}

\begin{getreference}
We have \printnumber{} columns, describing the user:
\begin{enumerate}
\item ID --- users.name
\item Forename --- users\_profiles.first\_name
\item Surname --- users\_profiles.last\_name
\item Email --- users.mail
\item Primary Service --- services.name
\item Start date --- FROM\_UNIXTIME(users.created)
\item Employment Status --- users\_profiles.employment\_status
\end{enumerate}
\end{getreference}
\end{document}
```

#### Pros

One LaTeX run is required.

#### Cons

Only one level can be counted, precisely the outermost `enumerate` environment.

[image]