# enumeration label out of margin

Tags: margins, enumerate, labels

I am wring this enumerated list as part of my document. I created labels
as 
Step-I
Step-II
Step-III

However they went out of margin on left side which looks ugly. I have attached the rough picture of it. 
[image]
Is there any way that it stays in the margin and move to right instead of moving towards left. The code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{enumerate}[label = {[Step-\Roman*]}]
\item 
\item
\item 
\item
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Thanks for the help. I ran into another problem of margin. The text is not moving to more of right. [image]

```
\begin{enumerate}[label = {[Step-\arabic*]},align=left]
\item {\color{bl} (Choose an elliptic curve)} Randomly choose an elliptic curve $E$ over $\Z_n$
      and point $P(x,y) \in E_{a,b}(\Z_n).$ Then again choose randomly $a,x,y\in \Z_n$ and
      calculate $b = y^2-x^3-ax.$ Compute $\gcd(4a^3+27b^2,n).$ If $\gcd(4a^3+27b^2,n)\neq 1,$
      then $E$ is not an elliptic curve. Choose another pair $(E,P)$ and repeat. \\
      If $\gcd(4a^3+27b^2,n)=1$ move to next step.
\item {\color{bl} (Compute $[m]P)$} Select a positive integer $m$ and compute the point $[m]P)
      \in E_{a,b}(\Z_n).$  
\item 
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to make enumerate items align at left margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29322/5764)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `align= left`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}    

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{enumerate}[label = {[Step-\Roman*]},align=left]
\item
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...an option with `widest` also exist. See [How to make enumerate items align at left margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29322/5764)

Comment: When using left option, it is not correctly aligned to left always. AboAmmar's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,calc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label={[Step-\Roman*]},leftmargin=\widthof{[Step-III]}+\labelsep]
\item first item
\item second item
\item third item
\item fourth item
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```