Getting the Maximum Width of a List of Items
I'm trying to write a command to get the maximum width of a (comma separated) list of items, for example \myLengthCommand{lorem,ipsum,lorem ipsum} should return the width of the text "lorem ipsum".
I have tried using egreg's \maxlength function from this answer coupled with \widthof from the calc package, so
\maxlength{\widthof{lorem},\widthof{ipsum},\widthof{lorem ipsum}}

but \widthof doesn't seem to return the length in the form that \maxlength accepts.
Furthermore, it would be nice to avoid having to write \widthof before each argument.
The code
\newlength{\myFirstLength}
\setlength{\myFirstLength}{\widthof{lorem}}

\newlength{\mySecondLength}
\setlength{\mySecondLength}{\widthof{ipsum}}

\newlength{\myThirdLength}
\setlength{\myThirdLength}{\widthof{lorem ipsum}}

\maxlength{\myFirstLength,\mySecondLength,\myThirdLength}

does return the desired result, but this becomes impractical with many arguments.
The code
\maxof{\widthof{lorem},\maxof{\widthof{ipsum},\widthof{lorem ipsum}}}

also works, but nesting \maxofs again becomes impractical.
Any help would be much appreciated.

As pointed out in the comments, I haven't been clear about how I intend to use this length, my apologies for that.
I have an enumerate with custom labels, and I'm using a slight variation of Werner's answer to another question, along with user31729's answer to another question to left align them:
\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\maxof{\widthof{\ref{Item1}},\maxof{\widthof{\ref{Item2}},\widthof{\ref{Item3}}}},leftmargin=!]
   \myitem{Custom Label} An item \label{Item1}
   \myitem{Another Label} An item \label{Item2}
   \myitem{Maybe a Very Long Label} An item \label{Item3}
\end{enumerate}

My goal is to replace the labelwidth=<nested maxofs> in optional argument of the enumerate with something along the lines of
labelwidth=\myLengthCommand{\ref{Item1},\ref{Item2},\ref{Item3}}

for more automation in case I add more labels/change some existing ones.

This might be an xy-problem. Can you add some background information what you are trying to do with the width?

Thanks for your comment, you're completely right, I've added an explanation to my question. Apologies for not being more specific

Can you either make a compilable example or show a screenshot of how the list should look like?

I've managed to get the list how I had intended using ljguo's answer, the goal was essentially the same as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29322/how-to-make-enumerate-items-align-at-left-margin, only with custom labels rather than numbers. In my case it wasn't always clear which was the longest when two labels were of similar length, taking the max of the references to these labels solved the issue, and will also update automatically if I change a particular label so that it is no longer necessarily the longest

Is this what you want?
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new:Npn \__get_max_length:nN #1#2 {
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 0pt }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } {
      \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {##1}
      \dim_compare:nT {\l_tmpa_dim < \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box}
      {
        \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
      } 
    }
    \dim_set_eq:NN #2 \l_tmpa_dim
  }

  \NewDocumentCommand{\myLengthCommand}{}{\__get_max_length:nN}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}

\myLengthCommand{lorem,ipsum,lorem ipsum}{\mylength}

\the\mylength

\end{document}

output: 53.97234pt.

you can use:
\newlength{\mylength}

\myLengthCommand{\ref{Item1}, \ref{Item2}, \ref{Item3}}\mylength

\begin{enumerate}[labelwidth = \mylength]
   ...
\end{enumerate}


This is great, thank you very much for your help! As samcarter points out in their comment, I should probably have been more specific about my use for the length, would it be possible for the function to return the length itself rather than assign it to a variable first? My aim is to be able to set labelwidth=myLengthCommand{A,B,etc} in the optional arguments for enumerate with enumitem. I've updated my question to make my intended use a bit clearer. Thanks again!

I've re-edited my answer.

Apologies for the delay in my response, many thanks for your update
